# My PowerBI report, which is fed by Google Bigquery, is failing to refresh when online, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, firebase-analytics

I am currently running into some issues with the online refresh of PowerBI when refreshing a BigQuery data source. I have created 9 views on top of the firebase analytics table that is being fed into BigQuery. Whereas the refresh from PowerBI Desktop always succeeds, the online refresh often (80% of cases)  fails, with the following error message:

> ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error
>   interacting with REST API: Couldn't connect to server ERROR [HY000]
>   [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error interacting with REST
>   API: Couldn't connect to server Table: vwDevices.

I contacted Microsoft about this, and their PowerBI product team believes the problem arises at BigQuery.

Is anyone familiar with this error message or does anyone have an idea what I should troubleshoot?

Thanks!
Jaap

Comment: Interesting, if the desktop version and online verson are behaving differently.  BigQuery's REST API/authentication should work the same regardless of who/what is calling it.  My first thought is that the desktop/online version aren't handling authentication the exact same way.

Comment: The one thing that I can imagine being different, is that PowerBI Service shoots all the request to the database at the exact same time, whereas Desktop waits for 1 to finish before starting the next.

Comment: I agree that this seems to be more related to the way PowerBI performs the requests/handles the responses, than to BigQuery itself. If you think this could be related to BigQuery, chances are that troubleshooting needs to be done. In that sense, I would recommend you to create a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659), where GCP engineers can communicate with you and help you investigate this.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this as have the same issue